# Get child key ( number ) - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get child number !

Here is my

`jsfiddle.net/Eagle_Design/tow0fyyz/2/`

The code :

**Html:**

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='daniel'>1</div>  (in the link : return 1) ok 
    <div class='daniel'>2</div>  (in the link : return 2) ok
    <div>not me</div>
    <div>not me</div>
    <div class='daniel'>3</div>  (in the link : return 5) problem 
    <div class='daniel'>4</div>  (in the link : return 6) problem 
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.parent .daniel').click(function(){
        alert($(this).index()+1);
    });

});
```

-

Comment: what do you mean by key? Explain better

Comment: @Parixit did you see the link ?

Comment: PUT the code in the question. Using a code block to get around the restriction is bad.

Comment: @epascarello http://jsfiddle.net/Eagle_Design/tow0fyyz/2/

Comment: Code still is not in the question....Do you realize stackoverflow has the same type of abilities as JSFiddle. Click the snipplet button.

Comment: @epascarello post has been updated ! --- solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no child_of() method in jquery. You should rather use `.index()`

```
$('.parent .daniel').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().find('.daniel').index(this)+1);
});
```

Comment: did you get the problem ?

Comment: @danialdezfooli: yes. you want index of clicked element in its parent right??